# Propagation of regularity for the heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb R^N$.

Let $u_0 \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $f \in L^\infty((0,T)\times\Omega)$ and consider the following boundary value problem for the heat equation:
$$
\begin{cases} u_t - \Delta u = f \\
u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0\\
u(0) = u_0
\end{cases}
$$

Fix $x_0 \in \Omega$, $U$ a neighborhood of $x_0 \in \Omega$, and assume that $u_0 \in C^k(U)$, and $f \in C^k([0,T) \times U)$. Is it true that there exists a unique (weak) solution of the heat equation that is regular in $V$, that is $u \in C^k([0,T)\times V) \cap L^\infty$, where $V$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ which is contained in $U$?

Also, do we have regularity up to the boundary of $\Omega$ if we assume $u_0 = \Delta u_0 = 0$?

---

I'd also like to draw your attention to a more general question that has appeared on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330884/regularity-result-for-the-boundary-value-problem-for-the-heat-equation).

---

Note that I'm talking about the behavior of $u(t, \cdot)$ for $t$ in the time interval $[0,T]$, not just in $[\epsilon, T]$.

That's why I'm talking about the regularity of the initial data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. Consider the two auxiliary problems

$$\left\{
\begin{eqnarray}
&v_t - \Delta v &= 0 \\
&v(0) &= u_0
\end{eqnarray}
\right.$$

and

$$\left\{
\begin{eqnarray}
&w_t - \Delta w &= f \\
&w(0) &= 0
\end{eqnarray}
\right.$$

where we are looking for $v$ and $w$ in $L^\infty _0 (\Omega)$.

The first problem is just the heat equation on $\Omega$: this means that if $h : (0, \infty) \times \Omega \times \Omega \to (0, \infty)$ is the heat kernel of $\Omega$ (which is known to be in $C^\infty (\Omega) \cap L^p (\Omega)$ for all $p>1$), then it is known that

$$v(t,x) = \int _\Omega h(t,x,y) \ u_0 (y) \ \mathrm d y \ .$$

(This mimicks the convolution operator, because there is no convolution on $\Omega$ since $\Omega$ is not a group under the addition of vectors). This operation is "smoothing", i.e. regardless of how ugly $u_0$ is, $v$ will always be smooth (i.e. $C^\infty$).

The second problem is non-homogeneous, so we attack it with the usual tool: [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle). This means that we consider yet another problem, namely

$$\left\{
\begin{eqnarray}
&W^s _t - \Delta W^s &= 0 \\
&W^s (0,s) &= f(s,x)
\end{eqnarray}
\right.$$

which again has the (smooth) solution $W^s (t,x) = \int _\Omega h(t,x,y) \ f(s,y) \ \mathrm d y$. From this we obtain (with Fubini's theorem at the end)

$$w(t,x) = \int _0 ^t W^s (t,x) \ \mathrm d s = \int _0 ^t \int _\Omega h(t,x,y) \ f(s,y) \ \mathrm d y \ \mathrm d s = \int _\Omega h(t, x, y) \int _0 ^t f(s,y) \ \mathrm d s \ \mathrm d y$$

which is seen with the naked eye to be smooth.

Finally, the sum $u = v + w$ clearly is a solution to the original problem, and is obviously smooth. This means that you get much more than just $C^k$ regularity, and this is because $h$ is $C^\infty$ and this is all that matters. It is also an elementary application of Hölder's inequality to check that $u$ is bounded (because $v$, $W^s$ and $w$ are and $\Omega$ has finite measure).

To show that $u(t, \cdot) = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ it is enough to notice that $h(t,x,y) = 0$ as soon as either $x \in \partial \Omega$, or $y \in \partial \Omega$ (again, this is from the general theory concerning the heat kernel). This implies that $v(t, \cdot) = 0$ and $W^s (t, \cdot) = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, whence $w(t, \cdot) = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, hence $u(t, \cdot) = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.

Smoothness in $t=0$ is again easy; I shall prove it for the first derivative, and then a simple induction does the rest:

$$\partial_t u(t,x) = \partial_t (v(t,x) + w(t,x)) = \partial_t \left( \int _\Omega h(t,x,y) \ u_0 (y) \ \mathrm d y + \int _\Omega h(t, x, y) \int _0 ^t f(s,y) \ \mathrm d s \ \mathrm d y \right) = \\
\int _\Omega \partial_t \ h(t,x,y) \ u_0 (y) \ \mathrm d y + \int _\Omega \partial_t \left( h(t, x, y) \int _0 ^t f(s,y) \ \mathrm d s \right) \mathrm d y = \\
\int _\Omega \Delta h(t,x,y) \ u_0 (y) \ \mathrm d y + \int _\Omega \left( \partial_t \ h(t, x, y) \int _0 ^t f(s,y) \ \mathrm d s + h(t, x, y) \ \partial_t \int _0 ^t f(s,y) \ \mathrm d s \right) \mathrm d y = \\
\int _\Omega \Delta h(t,x,y) \ u_0 (y) \ \mathrm d y + \int _\Omega \left( \Delta h(t, x, y) \int _0 ^t f(s,y) \ \mathrm d s + h(t, x, y) \ f(t,y) \right) \mathrm d y$$

which is easily seen to be continuous in $t=0$ (use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem and the standard fact that $\lim _{t \to 0} h(t,x,y) = \delta_x$ - Dirac's distribution). (Also, notice that it doesn't matter if you apply $\Delta$ in $x$ or in $y$ - things remain smooth anyway, because $h$ is so.)

For uniqueness, you want to show that the problem

$$\left\{
\begin{eqnarray}
&u_t - \Delta v &= 0 \\
&u(0) &= 0
\end{eqnarray}
\right.$$

has a unique solution in $L^\infty _0 (\Omega)$. But this, again, is standard knowledge; for instance, you could show it with [the approach that uses the energy functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322968). Or you could use the weak maximum principle.

All of the above holds in the context that I am familiar with, namely that $\partial \Omega$ be smooth. I believe, though, that the same general theory holds when $\partial \Omega$ is only Lipschitz, it's just that the proofs become more technical.

Comment: I belive that for the solution to be smooth up to the boundary you need compatibility conditions: $u_0= \Delta u_0 = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. However, my doubt is the following: Fix $x_0 \in \Omega$, $U$ a neighborhood of $x_0 \in \Omega$, and assume that $u_0 \in C^k(U)$, and $f \in C^k([0,T) \times U)$. Is it true that there exists a unique (weak) solution of the heat equation that is regular in $V$, that is $u \in C^k([0,T)\times V) \cap L^\infty$, where $V$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ which is contained in $U$? Could you address this issue more explicitly?

Comment: 1) Smoothness is a local property, the values of $u$ "far away at the boundary" do not matter. Since $h$ is smooth in $t$ and $x$, so will be everything else that emerges from it (use, for instance, Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, or any other theorem about the differentiability of integrals with respect to parameters). 2) You ask about *local* smoothness of order $k$, I am showing you something much stronger: *global* regularity of order $\infty$, and this is independent of the regularity of $u_0$ and $f$.

Comment: Just to be clear: your statement is that $u$ is smooth in any set $O \subset \subset \Omega$ (i.e. away from the boundary of $\Omega$) without assuming $u_0 = \Delta u_0 = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$? Also: could you add a remark in your answer to show what role do the compatibility conditions $u_0 = \Delta u_0 = 0$ play in proving smoothness up to the boundary?

Comment: 1) $u$ is smooth on $\Omega$ regardless of any boundary condition. In particular, it is smooth on any $O \Subset \Omega$ regardless of any boundary condition. 2) The "compatibility" conditions play absolutely no role in smoothness. 3) Finally, a remark that maybe I should have included in my post: notice that $h(t,x,y) = 0$ whenever $x \in \partial \Omega$ or $y \in \partial \Omega$ (this is by the construction of $h$). This implies that $v(t,x) = 0$ and $W^s (t,x) = 0$ whenever $x \in \partial \Omega$, hence $u(t, \cdot) = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: Are you sure? That doesn't sound right: I think you need the compatibility conditions to get smoothness in $\bar \Omega$ (i.e. up to the boundary).

Comment: @Lao: I regret the time that I have wasted conceiving an answer that is not understood. Please keep this in mind for the future: when asking a question, it is important to already master the prerequisites of the subject. This insures that you will understand the answer. Also, allow me to remind you that the answers in the Stack Exchange network are not supposed to be a substitute for courses and lecture notes.

Comment: Now maybe I see the confusion that might have arisen from my questions: when I say $u$ smooth I mean $u(t, \cdot)$ for $t$ in the time interval $[0,T]$, not just in $[\epsilon, T]$. That's why I'm talking about the initial data and its compatibility at the boundary: I need to get regularity up to time $t=0$.

Comment: @Lao If you want regularity up to the boundary, boundary should be at least as smooth as the solution, perhaps even something like $\partial\Omega\in C^{k+\alpha}$, $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: @Lao: You also get smoothness in $t=0$, see my edit.

Comment: @Andrew: This could be true, I usually work in the smooth category. Non-smooth boundary does not exist in my professional worldview. :) Could you give a reference?

Comment: @AlexM. That's how it is in most works. Exceptions are scarce. For the first BVP perhaps one can reason as follows. If $f\equiv0$ and $u_0>0$  by Zaremba-Giraud theorem for say $\partial \Omega \in C^2$ one has $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}>0$ on $\partial \Omega\times (0,T)$ so the side boundary $\partial \Omega\times (0,T)$ is a level surface of the function $u$. And it's smoothness depends on smoothness of $u$.

Comment: @Lao also the amount of compatibility conditions depends on $k$. Say, for $u\in C(\bar \Omega\times [0,T])$ it is enough $u_0|_{\partial\Omega}=0$, for  $u\in C^2(\bar \Omega\times [0,T])$ it is $u_0|_{\partial\Omega}=\Delta u_0|_{\partial\Omega}=0$, for  $u\in C^4(\bar \Omega\times [0,T])$ it is $u_0|_{\partial\Omega}=\Delta u_0|_{\partial\Omega}=\Delta^2 u_0|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ etc.

Comment: @Andrew: Am I right to believe that the compatibility conditions are necessary only for differentiability in $x$ and $y$ in some neighbourhood of $\partial \Omega$? Because away from the spatial boundary I'd say that the convolution of $u_0$ with the heat kernel of $\Omega$ seems to give smoothness "for free".

Comment: @AlexM. It seems that, when you pass to the limit to get smoothness in $t=0$ at a point $x_0$, you do need smoothness for the inital data. Otherwise how can you complete the newly added computation?

Comment: @Andrew I see, it does seem that the amount of compatibility conditions depends on $k$. Thank you. But how can you show smoothness up to the boundary (for $t \in [0,T]$) under these assumptions?

Comment: @Lao: For smoothness towards $t=0$ indeed, some smoothness of $u_0$ and $f$ helps. In fact, it seems that you only get $u$ to be smooth of order $[ \frac k 2 ]$ (when you integrate by parts in my formulae, $\Delta$ consumes $2$ derivatives from $u_0$ and $2$ from $f$). I believe that you may get away with it, though, even if $u_0$ and $f$ are not necessarily smooth, but in the Sobolev space $H^{2k} (\Omega)$ (in order to get $u$ smooth at $t=0$ of order $k$).

Comment: @AlexM. I see. So how should one conclude the proof (restarting from the expression $$\int _\Omega \Delta h(t,x,y) \ u_0 (y) \ \mathrm d y + \int _\Omega \left( \Delta h(t, x, y) \int _0 ^t f(s,y) \ \mathrm d s + h(t, x, y) \ f(t,y) \right) \mathrm d y$$ in the post) using this information?

Comment: @Lao: You are new around; one unwritten rule of the Stack Exchange network is that you shouldn't expect people to do every tiny detail for you. We are here to help and get you started, but we can't do the whole work in your place (remember that we are unpaid volunteers). Anyway, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/919375) you will find a quite detailed answer explaining the smoothing property of the heat semigroup, in particular at $t=0$. The answer is again given assuming some Sobolev regularity of $u_0$, which is quite the natural setting for the problem.

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, only near $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: @Andrew: Notice, though, that the OP asks about regularity in the spatial variables only on open subsets $U \subseteq \Omega$, so it's not clear why this whole discussion about the compatibility conditions, which play no role for spatial smoothness away from $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you very much: I do appreciate your answer and the effort you put into writing it and into replying to my comments. Although I must remark that the details on the regularity (in time and space) up to the initial time $t=0$ and the regularity assumptions required on the initial data to obtain them are the crux of the issue for me.